# Will you have the suit ready

Tags: meaning

I have some difficulty understanding the meaning of the following sentence

> The tailor said to him, "Will you have the suit ready by tomorrow evening?"

It is a sentence given in my exercise. No other context is provided

Comment: Semantically (meaning), it's equivalent to *Will **the suit** be ready by tomorrow?* Syntactically (grammar) it's the same usage as *I will **have** you flogged!* *(I will **cause** you to be flogged)*, so you could "deconstruct + rephrase" the "suit" version as *Will you **cause it to be the case** that the suit is ready tomorrow?*

Comment: But I think, that person should ask this question to the tailor

Comment: What is the exercise? What does it ask you to do with this sentence?

Comment: @PiyushYadav: Ooops! I didn't take in that part of the *specific meaning in context!* Actually, the only way to consider it "valid" is to understand it as a ***very*** weird version of the usage in [*Would you have me abandon my principles*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Would+you+have+me+abandon%22) *(is that what you're expecting me to do?)*. It's even more weird because the tailor asks ***will you*** rather than ***would you***, but the word ***have*** thus approximates to "require" [something to be true]. Specifically, *Do you **require** that it should be ready by tomorrow?*

Comment: Where did you get the sentence? It might be some weird thing to do with Indian English finding the usage "acceptable" (it's certainly not, to mainstream Anglophones). Or maybe it's just poor phrasing from a non-native speaker.

Comment: Oh, wow, I haven't even considered that reading (~"Do you *will it* to be ready by then?" or ~"Do you want to have it ready by then?"). Certainly sounds like something they're taught as "*proper* English". Outside of that context, I'd interpret it to mean that the tailor wants the person to prepare their suit somehow. Perhaps they don't want to do their work on it if it's dirty or something? Or maybe the tailor is talking to their assistant. Heck, maybe it's the tailor's tailor! I think it's more likely that whoever wrote that got a little confused as to who was telling what to whom, though.

Comment: It appears so straight-forward to me that I couldn't even guess what you're having trouble with. Please tell us why you are confused about this sentence. Is it the vocabulary? Is it the sentence structure? Have you checked a dictionary first?

Answer (score 1):

Say now the suit is torn or ripped.The tailor is now asking a person that knows how to sow

> "will the suit be fixed and ready to be sold tommorow evening?"

(ime just saying fixed so you understand because the suit has to be fixed
or decorated to be ready to give back to the tailor)

Meaning that she/he is asking if the dress will be ready to be sold somewhere at 5pm to 10pm - those are the evening times

Answer (score -2):

> I have some difficulty understanding the meaning of the following sentence

> The tailor said to him, "Will you have the suit ready by tomorrow evening?"

---

> "**Will you have the suit ready by tomorrow evening?**"

means

(will) [**are you able to] have the suit** (ready)[**prepared} by tomorrow evening?**.

**Note**. It is not unusual for a tailor to ask this question. A tailot measures the customer and very often cuts the cloth for the items of clothing. However the more time consuming and less critical sewing of the seams is usually done by a "seamster" or his female counter part a  "seamstress".

• Seamstress is a term applied to a female who sews as an occupation.

---

> **will modal verb** (**ABLE**/WILLING)  [C.E.Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/will) (also 'll) used to talk about what someone or something is able or willing to do:

> **ready** adjective (**PREPARED**) example Dinner's ready!  [C.E.Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ready)

Comment: Actually, this *isn't* right. The ***customer*** might say those words ***to the tailor*** with the meaning you give here. But for the ***tailor*** to say it with that meaning simply wouldn't make sense. You therefore have to parse it as ***will*** being a less common alternative to ***Would** you [like it to be the case that] the suit is ready by tomorrow?* As in ***Is that your wish**?*

Comment: Ugh, @FumbleFingers, I assume the exact opposite:  the tailor is asking if the customer will have the suit in her possession, ready to hand over to the tailor, for the tailor to start alterations, by tomorrow. (Say the customer is receiving a new suit in the mail.)

Comment: @whiskeychief: Okay - I can get my head around that interpretation too. But my gut reaction is to say *both* interpretations require a bit of "contrivance", so it's still a *terrible* example to come up with in the context of teaching people how to use normal English in normal contexts.

Comment: Please remember in past times and even today in high end shops, The tailor is the boss and usually does not do the manual work. He is most probably asking a member of his staff if they will have the suit ready. Which would be his normal duties as the supervisor and customer liaison.